# Drawing 2d lines spaced on a z axis in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, 3d

I currently have a Silverlight 4 app that draws some simple 2d layouts with lines. I'd like to draw multiple 2d line layouts but space them along a z axis, then rotate so I can see multiple layouts from an angle.

Do I need to go to a full on 3d framework to accomplish this in SL4? Eager to learn from anyone else that might have a short cut as all my objects in the layout are 2d, they just need to be spaced in a 3d way.

Comment: btw, I am aware of Balder, I'd prefer to not use an addon if possible.

Comment: I found this handing Silverlight 2 article by Declan Brennan:

Comment: Your question lacks specifics "spaced in a 3d way" doesn't really indicate well what you want. (BTW don't use comments to add details to your question, just edit your question to improve it)

Answer (score 0):

Whilst your question currently lacks clarity there are a couple features you might consider.

A UI element as a `RenderTransform` property so you could assign a `ScaleTransform` on various shapes to create a sense of different instances of a shape being at different depths.

Are you looking to generate perspective on an individual shape as if the shape is rotate about the X or Y axis so that part of the shape is closer to the viewer and part is further away?  In that case you can assign a `PlaneProjection` to the shape's `Projection` property to achieve that.